# How to use an expression in the replacement side of the perl substitution operator?

Tags: regex, perl, substitution

I'm pretty new to perl and facing one issue. This might sound as a silly question but I want to understand it well.

So I've a string variable containing a substring which I want to replace with a string of hashes.

```
my $l_filedata = 'abcOVERRIDE_CONTAINS_FUNCTIONSasdfghjk';
```

and

```
my $hash_ref = {};
Dumper($hash_ref->{'ContainsMessage'}); # This returns a hash and I've maintained it under scalar variable

Output
------
{
  '23.2.10103' => 1,
  '23.2.10101' => 1,
  '23.2.10102' => 1
}
```

So I want to perform a find-replace operation and the way I'm doing it is

```
$l_filedata =~ s/OVERRIDE_CONTAINS_FUNCTIONS/eval(Dumper($hash_ref->{'ContainsMessage'}))/g;
```

I'm trying to convert the hash to a string using Dumper and then want to replace the string with that Dumper-returned string. But it's always returning me `abceval(Dumper(HASH(0xe88f00)))asdfghjk`. I think the replacement expression is getting treated as string not an expression.

When I do it like this -

```
my $temp = Dumper($hash_ref->{'ContainsMessage'});
$l_filedata =~ s/OVERRIDE_CONTAINS_FUNCTIONS/$temp/g;
```

It's working as expected. Can someone tell me what am I missing here?

Comment: "_I think the replacement expression is getting treated as string not an expression._" -- correct, this is how the substitution operator works.  But with the modifier `/e` it evaluates the replacement side as code.  So slap `e` on it, `s/../Dumper(...)/ge`, and it'll work.

Comment: Btw, the code you show doesn't make sense -- you declare (an empty) hashref and then supposedly manipulate its value (it's empty!) ... Also, the comment in Perl is `#`, not `//`

Comment: Thanks @zdim for clarifying. It worked and I understood the difference now. It was a typo(used // instead of #) which I corrected now. And talking about hash_ref I've not given the code that populates the hash, I felt that's not necessary, instead I displayed it's content using Dumper

Comment: "_And talking about hash_ref ..._" -- OK (I thought so) -- it's just better, I think, to use snippets of valid code.  At least like `my $hash_ref = {}; ...  Dumper(...etc` (broken into lines, with ellipses on one line indicating more code).  May seem like nit picking but it's a better look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `e` flag to treat the replacement part as code to evaluate rather than the body of string literal.

```perl
s/OVERRIDE_CONTAINS_FUNCTIONS/ Dumper( $hash_ref->{ ContainsMessage } ) /eg
```

But do you really want to dump the structure multiple times? The following (which you already mentioned) is probably the way to go:

```perl
my $replacement = Dumper( $hash_ref->{ ContainsMessage } );

s/OVERRIDE_CONTAINS_FUNCTIONS/$replacement/g
```

---

```perl
s{...}{...}
```

is equivalent to

```perl
s{...}{ qq{...} }e
```

This means that

```perl
s{...}{eval(Dumper(...))}
```

is equivalent to

```perl
s{...}{ qq{eval(Dumper(...))} }e
```

But you simply want

```perl
s{...}{ Dumper(...) }e
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your question about running code on the replacement side of a substitution ?
Then this is the form `s///e` or even `s///ee`,
Beware this is tricky territory though.

But I don't think thats the question.  It would be better to arange the constant replacement ahead
of time.

Try a conservative and performant approach.

```
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $hash =
{
  '23.2.10103' => 1,
  '23.2.10101' => 1,
  '23.2.10102' => 1
};
my $output = Dumper($hash);
$output =~ s/^\$VAR.*|\R?^\s*};.*\s*//mg;

my $data  = "This one : OVERRIDE_CONTAINS_FUNCTIONS \n\n and here too: OVERRIDE_CONTAINS_FUNCTIONS";

$data =~ s/OVERRIDE_CONTAINS_FUNCTIONS/ $output /g;

print($data, "\n");
```

Output

```
This one :
          '23.2.10102' => 1,
          '23.2.10101' => 1,
          '23.2.10103' => 1

 and here too:
          '23.2.10102' => 1,
          '23.2.10101' => 1,
          '23.2.10103' => 1
```

Comment: `e` is NOT tricky territory.  `eval`/`ee` is, but why did you even mention `eval`/`ee`?!?! It has nothing to do with "running code on the replacement side of a substitution" as you claim. That what `e` does. The second `e` is (deceptively) unrelated to that.

Comment: @ikegami - Don't know what you're talking about, never mentioned eval, never made claims about anything. You mean like `///ee` like this  `($tt='&#810254;')=~s/&#(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d);/"print chr $2$4$1$6$3$5"/ee;` I been in Perl before. Mostly a regex expert these days, big time.

Comment: But you did mention `ee` (which is `e` +`eval EXPR`). There was no reason to mention `ee`. It's unrelated to the question.

Comment: Re "*never made claims about anything.*", Of course you did. You made a number of claims, including "Then this is the form `s///e` or even `s///ee`" and "Beware this is tricky territory though." Both of these claims are wrong.